# Como armazenar dados do input select com Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Não consigo enviar os dados selecionados para a request:

```
<select name="tipo_id" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <option value=""></option>
    @foreach ($tipos as $tipo )
    <option name="tipo_id" value="{{$tipo->id}}">{{$tipo->description}}</option>
    @endforeach
```

Erro:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'tipo_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `titulos` (`valor`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (200, 2019-02-26 17:01:06, 2019-02-26 17:01:06))
```

Comment: Tenta tirar o atributo `name` da sua option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro do SQL está dizendo que você não possui o field `tipo_id` na em sua Entidade Titulos. Verifique se há o campo `tipo_id` ou se está com o nome diferente na Entidade